# Tensor product of a very ample line bundle with a torsion line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, line-bundles

Is there an example of smooth projective surface $S$ having a very ample line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ and a $2$-torsion line bundle $\mathcal{T}$ such that $\mathcal{L}\otimes(\mathcal{T}^{-1})$ has no global sections?

I expect such an example to exist, but I have not been able to construct one.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4852488

Comment: @Sasha, are you saying to take $(S,\mathcal{L},\mathcal{T})=(C_1\times C_2, L_1\boxtimes L_2, \xi_1\boxtimes\xi_2)$ with $C_i, L_i,\xi_i$ as in that answer?

Comment: This is one option. Another is to take $(C_1,L_1,\xi_1)$ as in the answer, while taking $C_2$ to be any curve, $L_2$ any ample line bundle, and $\xi_2 = \mathcal{O}_{C_2}$.